# Breake long sentence in a \multirow cell whitin a \longtable

Tags: longtable, multirow

I have a `\longtable` with `\multirow` cells, as in the picture attached.

Here, if I try to break the line and there isn't enough space at the bottom of the page, the remaining part of the sentence goes outside of the table.

Same issue if I don't force any interruption but the sentence is quite long.

Do you think `\pagebreak` is the only solution?

Note:

- I know that I'm giving a wrong number of lines to `\multirow` (i.e. `\multirow[t]{5}{=}{item 1\newline pos. A}` instead of `\multirow[t]{8}{=}{item 1\newline pos. A}` but I'm working with thousands of lines which will change in length in a future revision of the doc, so, for me, is easier to count the number of `\square` (anyway, this seems to not be the cause of my issue).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{10cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
COMPONENT & CHECKS DESCRIPTION & CHECKED – NOTE & CHECKED – NOTE\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
COMPONENT & CHECKS DESCRIPTION & CHECKED – NOTE & CHECKED – NOTE\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{item 1\newline pos. A} & check this doing that text text text text text text  & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
\hline
\multirow[t]{4}{=}{item 2\newline pos. B} & check this doing that text text text text text text  & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
\hline
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{item 3\newline pos. C} & check this doing that text text text text text text  & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
\hline
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{item 4\newline pos. D} & check this doing that text text text text text text  & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: issue with \multirow whitin \longtable]

Comment: What exactly does the expected output look like? Do you want both "item 4"  and "pos. D" to appear on the second page? If so, you could use `\\*` instead of `\\ ` whenever you want to prevet a pagebreak between the teo table rows.

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @leandriis, you should use `\\*` where you don't want a page break. To be more precise: if you want to keep a 'block' of lines together, use `\\*` between them, but use `\\` at the end to allow a page break there. In your example, the `\hline`s also allow a page break, so strictly speaking you could use `\\*` before it too, but I think it is cleaner not to do that.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{10cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
COMPONENT & CHECKS DESCRIPTION & CHECKED – NOTE & CHECKED – NOTE\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
COMPONENT & CHECKS DESCRIPTION & CHECKED – NOTE & CHECKED – NOTE\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{item 1\newline pos. A} & check this doing that text text text text text text  & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
\hline
\multirow[t]{4}{=}{item 2\newline pos. B} & check this doing that text text text text text text  & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
\hline
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{item 3\newline pos. C} & check this doing that text text text text text text  & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
\hline
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{item 4\newline pos. D} & check this doing that text text text text text text  & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\*
& check this doing that text text text text text text text text text text text text text & $\square\ldots$ & $\square\ldots$\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]